# TCP/IP simple file server in c problems with reading on the server in C

Tags: c, sockets

I will show you my server and client loop.

The fact is that i do a fwrite on my file i want to send in the client side, then i write it to the server, but the read of my server don't receive the totality of the bytes i write, like if some bytes are lost. How can i do to change that?

There is my Loops:

BUF and BUFF are equals to 1024.

Client.c:

```
  while(taille)
  {
  size=fread(buffer,1,BUF,f_read);
  write(sock, buffer,size);
  taille -=size;
  stat+=size;
  }
```

Server.c :

```
  //I do the loop with x to try to fix the bytes lost, but don't work :/
  int x = 0;
  while(size)
  {
   while(x!=BUFF)
   {
     x=read(service, mess_recu, BUFF);
   }
   fwrite(mess_recu,x,1,f_write);
   size-=x;
   x=0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you would imagine if you sent 1000 bytes into a socket you would be able to do a read and get 1000 bytes out. That isn't quite how things work.

What happens is somewhat more complicated as it depends on what type of socket you are using. With TCP the socket is stream oriented, so you will read however many bytes happen to be on the stream at the time you performed your read. Eventually this will add up to the total number of bytes you sent, but you will have to do multiple reads.

If you use datagram oriented sockets (like UDP). Your reads will correspond to datagrams sent over the wire. So for instance if you send a 700 byte datagram, you will receive a 700 byte datagram on the remote side. The problem is that unlike TCP, the individual reads and writes are not ordered with respect to each other such that if you send one packet of 5 bytes and a second of 7 bytes the reader is neither guaranteed any specific order not that it will get any packets at all.